# Developing Windows8 Apps on Windows 7 using MS VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-8

Can I develop Windows 8 Apps using VS 2012 on Windows7 platform, I have gone through the website, but they have mentioned that Windows 8 is mandatory?

Comment: Yes. Why do you need us to confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With certain exceptions, the Visual Studio 2012 Windows Store app authoring experience is restricted to Windows 8.

You may be able to get the command line tools working on Windows 7, but the IDE requires Windows 8.